# Chrome Extension: retitling a tab with tabs.create callback function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

After I create a set of tabs, I want to rename them with names that are saved in storage. I am trying to use `chrome.tabs.create`'s callback function to send a message to the content script to retitle the tabs. I am able to create the tabs but am unable to retitle the tabs.

In `popup.js` I have a loop that iterates through all of the tabs and calls `chrome.tab.create` in `background.js`.

## part of popup.js

```
groupButton.onclick = function()
{
    /* opens the tabs */
    for (var j = 0; j < group["tabCount" + i]; j++)
    {
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().createTab(group, i, j);
        // cannot use callback function because popup is immediately closed upon tab creation, have to use background script
        // chrome.tabs.create({"url": group["tabUrls" + i][j], "active": false});
    }
}
```

## background.js

```
function createTab(group, i, j)
{
    chrome.tabs.create({"url": group["tabUrls" + i][j], "active": false}, function(tab)
    {
        var tabTitle = group["tabNames" + i][j];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {getTitle: tabTitle}, function(response){});
    })
}
```

## content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if (request.title || request.name || request.getTitle)
    {
        document.title = request.title || request.name || request.getTitle;
    }
})
```

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. Maybe `group["tabNames" + i][j]` is `undefined`. Check if at least you get a message in your content script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that your content script hasn't finished loading in the new tab before the `createTab` callback sends a message to the tab, so the content script doesn't receive it.

You could have the content script request the new title from the background page when it loads, or you could listen for the new tab to finish loading, then send the message to the tab. The latter approach could look something like this:

```
var tabIdsToTitles = {};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
  if (tabIdsToTitles[tabId] && changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {getTitle: tabIdsToTitles[tabId]}, function(response){});
  }
});

function createTab(group, i, j)
{
    chrome.tabs.create({"url": group["tabUrls" + i][j], "active": false}, function(tab)
    {
        var tabTitle = group["tabNames" + i][j];
        tabIdsToTitles[tab.id] = tabTitle;
    })
}
```

I tested this approach after reproducing your issue, and it works.

You could also add a listener for each tab you create, then remove that listener once you've sent the message to the tab after the tab loads, to avoid having that listener running needlessly on changes to irrelevant tabs.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks!